# How to get case statement from another table in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table (T1) containing only one record that is a long `case when` statement, That is generated and saved in this table daily.

Now my task is to create another table (T2). This new table will use case statement from table T1 to populate one of its column.

I am trying below approach but it populates case statement as string in the column. While I want that case statement to be executed and values of case statement to be populated.

```
CREATE TABLE T2 AS 
SELECT 
COL1, 
COL2, 
T1.CASE_STATEMENT AS COL3, -- I WANT THIS TO BE REPLACED WITH CASE STATEMENT IN ANOTHER TABLE
COL4
FROM SOURCE_TABLE FULL OUTER T1 ON 1=1
```

Current Result:

```
+-----+------+------------+------+
|COL1 | COL2 |    COL3    | COL4 |
+-----+------+------------+------+
| V1  | V11  |CASE WHEN...| V23  |
+-----+------+------------+------+
| V2  | V12  |CASE WHEN...| V34  |
+-----+-------------------+------+
```

Expected Result: COL3 should be populated based on result of case statement

```
+-----+------+------------+------+
|COL1 | COL2 | COL3       | COL4 |
+-----+------+------------+------+
| V1  | V11  | v21        | V23  |
+-----+------+------------+------+
| V2  | V12  | v23        | V34  |
+-----+-------------------+------+
```

How can I achieve this?
I am using python to run my sql file.

I also tried setting up case statement using SET in snowflake but my case statement is too large for SET variable in snowflake.

`SET case_statement = (sql to generate case statement here`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do it with plain SQL. You need to use Stored Procedures.

Here is a sample:

```
create or replace table T1 ( case_statement varchar ) as 
select 'case when col2 > 10 then 1 else 0 end';

create or replace table source_table ( col1 varchar, col2 varchar ) as
select * from values (1,15),(2,9),(3,5);

create or replace procedure generate_table()
returns varchar
language sql
AS
declare
    my_case_statement varchar;
    ctas_statement varchar;
begin
    select case_statement into :my_case_statement from T1;
    ctas_statement := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T2 AS 
    SELECT 
    COL1, 
    COL2,' || :my_case_statement  || ' AS COL3
    FROM SOURCE_TABLE';
    execute immediate :ctas_statement;
    return :ctas_statement;
end;

call generate_table();

select * from t2;

+------+------+------+
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |   15 |    1 |
|    2 |    9 |    0 |
|    3 |    5 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
```

As you can see, col3 is the result of the CASE statement. I used "create or replace" - so be careful when running the scripts, don't overwrite your own tables :)